# jQuery Insertion Element Notation

Tags: jquery, syntax, insertion

I had someone help me out earlier and they used this notation to insert a paragraph with jQuery. I haven't seen it before.

```
$('<p />', {'class': 'preview',text: 'Test'}).insertAfter($uls.eq(0));
```

Inserts:

```
<p class="preview">Test</p>
```

How do I modify this code to insert the following instead?

```
<div class="preview"><p>Test</p></div>
```

I've tried: `$('<div />', {'class': 'preview',text: '<p>Test</p>'})`
But it parses the `<p>` tags as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `html` instead of `text`, something like this :

```
$('<div />', {'class': 'preview', html: '<p>Test</p>'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use HTML

```
     $('<div />', {'class': 'preview'}).html('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter($uls.eq(0));
```